# Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

In the Spark root directory, when I launch "sbt", a message will show up:

```
Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'.
```

What does this message imply? and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Have the same problem, not related to apache-spark at all. Just a simple sbt project with sbt-release. I really want to clean up and have warnings be real warnings, but I can't fix this one.

Answer (score 4):

Like Viktor Hedefalk already mentioned in his comment, the warning is not related to Apache Spark but to the configuration of sbt.

#### Root cause

Resolvers with the same name but a different URL or access method (http, https...) are defined in your `build.sbt` or in your sbt configuration.

#### Consequences

sbt cannot guarantee that the resolver used for that name is the one you expect.

#### Fix

Check your `build.sbt` for duplicate resolvers. Both `resolvers +=` and `publishTo :=` lines matter!

Also, check if `~/.sbt/repositories` exists and what's in there.

In my case, I was using the flag `-Dsbt.repository.config` and the configuration file was conflicting with my `build.sbt`.

#### References

https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/sxr/sbt/Defaults.scala.html#sbt.Classpaths.warnResolversConflict

https://gitter.im/sbt/sbt/archives/2015/06/26

Comment: In my case I had an old `~/.sbt/repositories` which used `http` instead of the `https` defined in `build.sbt`. Thanks! :)